# How can i fill my website chart from a database

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with some charts, where I fill the charts with a static data by using java script. I want to replace the static data with SQL data.

How can I do it ?

This is an example about what I have got. I don't want to write the data values like this; I want to insert it from SQL server.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "startDuration": 2,
    "dataProvider": [{
        "country": "USA",
        "visits": 4000,
        "color": "#FF0F00"
    }, {
        "country": "China",
        "visits": 1882,
        "color": "#FF6600"
    }, {
        "country": "Japan",
        "visits": 1809,
        "color": "#FF9E01"
    }, {
        "country": "Germany",
        "visits": 1322,
        "color": "#FCD202"
    }, {
        "country": "UK",
        "visits": 1122,
        "color": "#F8FF01"
    }, {
        "country": "France",
        "visits": 1114,
        "color": "#B0DE09"
    }, {
        "country": "India",
        "visits": 984,
        "color": "#04D215"
    }, {
        "country": "Spain",
        "visits": 711,
        "color": "#0D8ECF"
    }, {
        "country": "Netherlands",
        "visits": 665,
        "color": "#0D52D1"
    }, {
        "country": "Russia",
        "visits": 580,
        "color": "#2A0CD0"
    }, {
        "country": "South Korea",
        "visits": 443,
        "color": "#8A0CCF"
    }, {
        "country": "Canada",
        "visits": 441,
        "color": "#CD0D74"
    }, {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "visits": 395,
        "color": "#754DEB"
    }, {
        "country": "Italy",
        "visits": 386,
        "color": "#DDDDDD"
    }, {
        "country": "Taiwan",
        "visits": 338,
        "color": "#333333"
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "position": "left",
        "axisAlpha":0,
        "gridAlpha":0         
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "colorField": "color",
        "fillAlphas": 0.85,
        "lineAlpha": 0.1,
        "type": "column",
        "topRadius":1,
        "valueField": "visits"
    }],
    "depth3D": 40,
    "angle": 30,
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
    },    
    "categoryField": "country",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha":0,
        "gridAlpha":0

    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
     }

},0);

jQuery('.chart-input').off().on('input change',function() {
    var property    = jQuery(this).data('property');
    var target      = chart;
    chart.startDuration = 0;

    if ( property == 'topRadius') {
        target = chart.graphs[0];
    }

    target[property] = this.value;
    chart.validateNow();
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
    width       : 100%;
    height      : 435px;
    font-size   : 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="float: none !important;display: inline-block;">
            <label class="text-left">Top Radius:</label>
            <input class="chart-input" data-property="topRadius" type="range" min="0" max="1.5" value="1" step="0.01"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3" style="float: none !important;display: inline-block;">
            <label class="text-left">Angle:</label>
            <input class="chart-input" data-property="angle" type="range" min="0" max="89" value="30" step="1"/>    
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3" style="float: none !important;display: inline-block;">
            <label class="text-left">Depth:</label>
            <input class="chart-input" data-property="depth3D" type="range" min="1" max="120" value="40" step="1"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i found this website https://live.amcharts.com/new/edit/ i want to know the way that they import the data and show it like a charts

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server side programming language. Step 2: Learn how to use databases with it. Step 3: Output the data into your page in the format of the JS at the top of your question.

Comment: Too broad. How do you intend to run the server side code? What backend technology stack do you have access to? Javascript can't do this alone.

Comment: You need a model (table in sql) which has country,visits and color properties. You will get a list of model from db and serialize to json.

Comment: I was just wondering !! well ; what is the technology that can be used to do that

Comment: @dovesound Any technology which you can understand... ;

Comment: Any technology which can communicate with SQL database;